# Python Azure Blob Direct Upload

Tags: python, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to read a csv from Azure blob into Python as a stream and write it back to Azure blob directly. Read operation works perfectly fine butwriting output stream just writes an empty file into the blob. The following code works until print(df) but not after that.

Below is the code:

**Code:**

```
from io import BytesIO, StringIO

with BytesIO() as input_blob:   

  with BytesIO() as output_blob:

    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='aaaccc', account_key='*/*/*--')

    block_blob_service.get_blob_to_stream('test', 'Source.csv', input_blob)

    input_blob.seek(0)

    df=pd.read_csv(input_blob)

    print(df)

    copyfileobj(input_blob, output_blob)

    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream('test', 'OutFilePy.csv', output_blob)
```

Comment: what does `copyfileobj` function do? can you edit your question and paste the definition of that?

Comment: @Saher, copyfileobj copies the input stream to output stream.. I am trying to write the copied output_blob into blob storage but it just writes an empty file

Comment: I think the problem may be `input_blob`'s cursor is at EOF after `pd.read_csv`. A `input_blob.seek(0)` after `read_csv` maybe helpful.

Comment: Fantastic Sraw, it works!! one last question... what if i have to make some operations on dataframe and write the modified dataframe as stream into blob?

Comment: @Sraw You could move your comment to the answer to help more community members to find, thanks.

Comment: @Sraw Could you please move the answer from comment to answer to help the azure community ?

Comment: @AdamSmith-MSFT Done :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that after `pd.read_csv`, the cursor of `input_blob` is at EOF. So `copyfileobj` just copy nothing to `output_blob`.

You can just add an `input_blob.seek(0)` after `read_csv` to fix this problem.